# turn left side tab to right side

Tags: html, css

In this part of code tabs are left align. I try to make it right but it doesn't change. I add float:right but doesn't  work.

```
           <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8" >
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab"   navbar-right>
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" data- 
                toggle="tab">خانه</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">message</a></li>
                <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">setting</a></li>
            </ul>
```

css:

```
  .tab-pane {
  border:solid 1px #1A3E5E;
  border-top: 0; 
  width:60%;
  /*color of text below tabs*/
  background-color:#77ff16;
  padding:5px;}



     .my-tab .tab-pane1{border:solid 1px blue;}

  /* color of tabs */
  #myTab li a { border-color: blue;background-color:#A5C967; }
 /* color of active tab*/
  #myTab li.active a {border-bottom-color: transparent;background- 
color:Yellow; }
```

Comment: You don't have a `.tab-pane`in your HTML. The `border-color: blue;`  or transparent is meaningless since you don't have any other border properties defined. In order to align text to the right you do :`text-align:right`.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Bootstrap 4 has flexbox, Navbar alignment is much easier. Here are [updated examples for **left**, **right** and **center** in the Bootstrap 4 Navbar](http://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v), and [**many other alignment scenarios** demonstrated here](https://www.codeply.com/go/kTGlK9Axdk).

The [flexbox](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/), [auto-margins](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#auto-margins), and [ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order) utility classes can be used to align Navbar content as needed. There are many things to consider including the order and alignment of Navbar items (brand, links, toggler) on both large screens and the mobile/collapsed views. Here are several examples...

**Left, center(brand) and right links:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Navbar 2</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
        <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="//placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="rounded-circle">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

## **Bootstrap 3**

**Option 1** - Brand center, with left/right nav links:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}
```

---

**Option 2** - Left, center and right nav links:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}
```

**Option 3** - Center both brand and links

```
.navbar .navbar-header,
.navbar-collapse {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse  {
        display: block;
    }
```

}

P.S. this answer is from another similar question on stack overflow